# Origin of the definition of the electric potential of a black hole

Tags: thermodynamics, general-relativity, black-holes, potential

All the papers I’ve seen in black hole thermodynamics (e.g. arXiv:hep-th/9908022) define the electrostatic potential of a black hole with horizon Killing vector $\xi^a$ as

$$\Phi := \xi^a A_a \big|_{r \to \infty} - \xi^a A_a\big|_\text{Horizon},$$

where $A$ is the four-potential. Where does this definition come from? Could somebody show me/point me to a derivation of this definition please?

Comment: Well yes it does. That is not the point at all. There are many other definitions that reduce to this answer in the Schwarzschild case.